# HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden when endpoint is /tests/

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net Core app with the usual default routing set up in Startup.cs. My app has a `TestsController`, with some action routines, including an `Index()` routine.

I've never had a problem navigating to my app's `/tests/` or `/tests/index` endpoints before today. As of today, attempting to navigate to `/tests` gives me the IIS **HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden** error page. If I try to navigate to `/tests/index` then I get the IIS **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found** page.

All of the other endpoints in my app seem to work correctly. It's just the `/tests` endpoints that fail.

If I rename the controller from `TestsController` to `TestController` (remove the "s") then I have no problem navigating to either `/test` or `/test/index`.

So, this smells like IIS is maybe finding a `Tests` folder that it thinks I'm trying to list? But the only `Tests` folder I can see in Windows Explorer is in the `obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Razor\Views` folder. I don't think IIS is tripping over that.

One other data point: Yesterday, I ran into a weird problem where VS 2019 would load my project and immediately complain that "A process used by VS has encountered an unrecoverable error". I eventually figured out that this was caused (for some unknown reason) by the presence of a tag helper I was working on. Removing the tag helper code fixed that problem. But it's suspicious that now I have this new problem. On the presumption that the tag helper problem left some detritus behind, I deleted all of the bin and obj folders, deleted all of the NuGet packages, rebooted (a couple of times) and rebuilt everything. No luck, I still can't navigate to the `/tests` endpoint.

EDIT: Another data point: I just tried the same code on another machine, and it works correctly. The problem is isolated to the one machine.

**How do I ask IIS where it thinks it's finding a `tests` folder?**

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly helpful answer, but it's what I've got... I spent a frustrating week with MS tech support, with no resolution. In the end, I nuked the local repo and re-cloned it, and the problem went away.

It was really weird. If I simply renamed the parent directory for the solution and all of its projects then the problem went away. If I renamed the directory back to its original name then the problem came back.